# elastic search log configuration is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to enable logs in the elastic search server using the below link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html

I verified my index setting using the url
http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings

The result is below

```
{"myindex":{"settings":{"index":{"search":{"slowlog":{"threshold":{"fetch":{"warn":"1ms","trace":"1ms","debug":"1ms","info":"1ms"},"query":{"warn":"1ms","trace":"1ms","debug":"1ms","info":"1ms"}}}},"number_of_shards":"3","provided_name":"occindex","creation_date":"1508319257925","number_of_replicas":"2","uuid":"dVAWgk62Sgivzr2B_OuCzA","version":{"created":"5040399"}}}}}
```

As per the document, I expect the logs to be populated when the threshold is breached.

I have set 1 ms as the threshold in order to log all queries that are hitting elastic search

I observed that under logs folder  , the log files *elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log* and *elasticsearch.log* does not show the queries which are hitting elastic search.

Let me  know if my configuration is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The log worked after I inserted one record.

If you fire the query when there are no records in the index , the log was not updated